# Iterate through dictionary by indexes

Tags: python-3.x

How to bypass python out of box mechanism when an order of `items()` in the loop does not correspond to the order it supposes to be?

```
st = 'Tree'
freq = Counter(st)
sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
arr = []
for k, v in freq.items():
     for i in range(v):
         arr.append(k)
```

I expect to get in the first iteration pair: `('e', 2)`, but instead it is `('t', 1)`.
But sorting was applied to dictionary at row 3.

How to iterate dictionary in way it is sorted? (without applying underhood re-order)

**UPD**. The question has already been answered, however, will be good to know why dictionaries implemented in Python3 in that way.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, crashes with `NameError`.

Answer (score 1):

sort by keys:

```py
a = dict(b=3, c=5, a=10)

for k in sorted(a):
    print(f"{k}: {a[k]}")
```

and if you want to sort them by the values:

```py
a = dict(b=3, c=5, a=10)

for k, v in sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print(f"{k}: {a[k]}")
```

Comment: Use `v`, not `_`.

Comment: first example gave order as expected, second one doesn't work. however, for me first is enough. ty

Comment: @calm27 Huh? So you want to sort by key? Then why did you sort by value in your own attempt?

Comment: for the test case when str is 'Aabb', neither first or second doesn't work.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, show me where did I write I need to sort by key?

Comment: Now you forgot to use `v`.

Comment: @calm27 You said the first one (which sorts by key) works, and you accepted the answer.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, okay. so, it doesn't mean i wrote that need to sort by key, because the question description, perhaps, clearly indicates sort by values is expected. It showed me the correct output as Peter wrote, because of actually lucky coincidence. But overall, underhood sorting of a dictionary is still applied and changes the order.

Comment: As @Kelly Bundy pointed the question was not optimal. I was not sure what is the point, because you in your example was a bit of everrthing. Glad to help